# How do I calculate the total wattage of a dc to dc circuit?

Tags: dc-dc-converter, watts

I am trying to figure out the total wattage of the below assumed dc to dc converter circuit block diagram.

[image: dcTOdc]

Can I get it simply by just multiplying the total SUM of the system output voltages by total SUM of the system output Amps, like this:

(3.3 + 3.3 + 6 + 6 + 9) X (.5 + .5 + 2 + 2 + 2.5) =

(27.6V) X (7.5A) = 207W ???

Is that how we calculate it?

Comment: your equation says that each of the five circuits draws 7.5 A

Comment: @jsotola, true, good point! Thanks.

Comment: How many watts does the third DC/DC carry?

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica ,  50W

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No.  Those are the correct units, but the answer will be off.  This problem can be solved with simple physics plus common sense; specifically the conservation of energy plus the fact that no power conversion device is 100% efficient.

You need to calculate the power available from each output, by multiplying its current by its voltage (e.g. each one of your two 3.3V supplies needs 1/2 A, and so provides 1.75W).  Then you need to add all of those together.

The number you get is the maximum possible output power.  It's also the *theoretical minimum* of the maximum input power.  In reality you'll need to divide that by the efficiency of the supply (e.g. 80%).  If you really want to get down to details, each output will have its own efficiency, so you'd need to multiply each output power by the individual efficiency, then add those up.

Comment: Thanks for your help. In this case my total W should be approx 50W. Would you please elaborate about the efficiency thing. For the above system, TI WEBENCH tool says my system efficiency is around 90%. So, I divided 50 by 90 and got 0.56, is this 56 is my input power?

Comment: You divide 50 by 0.9 (90%) to get 56.

Comment: great, thanks again! I am planning to use 14V 5200mAh battery! So, it sounds I should be fine then!

Answer (score 0):

No, you multiply each individual voltage by the current taken by the load on that individual voltage to get the power on that individual circuit.

Step and repeat for each sub-supply then sum all the wattages to get the total power but, don’t forget to take into account any inefficiencies in the individual voltage conversions.

Around 35 to 40 watts is your likely answer.

Comment: @Anyaka, Nice. Thanks for the help. I got 50W.

Answer (score 0):

No. It's V x A for **each**, i.e. 3.3 V x 500 mA + 3.3 V x 500 mA... and once you understand that, you could add the currents for the two 3.3 V supplies and for the two 6V supplies.

Think of adding coins: 2 @ $.05 and 7 @ $.25 **cannot** be calculated by saying "That's 9 coins of $.30."

BTW, does the assignment mention the **efficiency** of the supply? If you need 20 W out and the supply is 50% efficient, you'd need twice as much, 40 W, input (and get 20 W of heat).

Comment: Cool. I appreciate your help!  TI WEBENCH tool says my system efficiency is around 90%, and I am planning to use 14V 5200mAh battery, that should be fine, right?